# How to count number of rows per window in streaming queries?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Scenario: Working on Spark Streaming in Structured SQL. I have to implement a "info" dataset about how many rows I've processed in the last "window".

A little bit of code.

```
val invalidData: Dataset[String] =
    parsedData.filter(record => !record.isValid).map(record => record.rawInput)

val validData: Dataset[FlatOutput] = parsedData
    .filter(record => record.isValid)
```

I have two `Dataset`. But since I'm working on Streaming I cannot perform a `.count` (Error raised: `Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()`)

```
val infoDataset = validData
    .select(count("*") as "valid")
```

but a new error occurs: `Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark` and I don't want to set outputMode as complete since I don't want total count from beginning, but just last "windowed" batch.

Unfortunately I don't have any column that I could register as watermark for these datasets.

Is there a way to know how many rows are processed in each iteration?

Comment: Why don't you use [StreamingQueryStatus](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryStatus) for this?

Comment: BTW, Is the counting part of the business logic or is this only for monitoring purposes?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski just for monitoring purposes

Comment: @JacekLaskowski btw, probably I found [StreamingQueryProgress](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/StreamingQueryProgress.html) more useful to my cause. Thank you a lot to pointed me out to that anyway. I will write probably my code as soon I finish to answer my own question

Answer (score -1):

It seems like [StreamingQueryStatus](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/StreamingQueryStatus.html) could be of some help.